# My draggable UI elements are also dragging camera? How do I prevent UI dragging from moving the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have UI elements that can be dragged, so that a prefab can be instantiated `OnDragEnd()`.  I am using below code attached to the UI buttons to achieve this

```
public class MyButton : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    ..
    ..
    ..


    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        dragRect.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta;
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // if we're on deploy cooldown, dont allow dragging this button
        if (disableDrag )
        {
            eventData.pointerDrag = null;
        }
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.screenPosition);
        Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            createUnit(hit);
            disableDrag = true;
        }
    }

}
```

This works fine without any problems, but recently I also implemented the ability to drag the camera. I attached the following code to my camera to achieve this:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementTime;
    public Vector3 newPosition;
    private Vector3 startPosition;
    public Vector3 dragStartPosition;
    public Vector3 dragCurrentPosition;
    public float xLimit1, xLimit2;
    float clampedX;
    Camera mainCamera;

    private void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        newPosition = transform.position;
        startPosition = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        HandleMouseInput();
        clampedX = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.x, xLimit1, xLimit2);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3 (clampedX, startPosition.y, startPosition.z), Time.deltaTime * movementTime);
    }

    void HandleMouseInput()
    {
        // when mouse is pressed,
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            {
                Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
                Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                float entry;

                if (plane.Raycast(ray, out entry))
                {
                    dragStartPosition = ray.GetPoint(entry);
                }
            }
        }
        // if it is still held down
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            {
                Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
                Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                float entry;

                if (plane.Raycast(ray, out entry))
                {
                    dragCurrentPosition = ray.GetPoint(entry);

                    newPosition = transform.position + dragStartPosition - dragCurrentPosition;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And the camera script works as well as it behaves as expected and the camera drags with mouse. But the problem is that when I drag my UI button onto screen that moves the camera also.

I tried to include the if condition of checking if its over a UI `if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())` But this does not seem to work, the camera still drags when I drag the UI button.

How do I make them work together?

Comment: I would check out [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1219873/how-can-i-get-ui-element-over-which-pointer-is-in.html). Another option is using RaycastAll but that is rather expensive. By exposing more information of the current Event System, it should allow you to determine various data such as if an element is hovered. But if you'd rather test the [RaycastAll](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1115464/ispointerovergameobject-not-working-with-touch-inp.html) you can try this.

Comment: For some reason when I originally viewed your code I missed the second snippet of holding the mouse. I do not know the exact issue but can help you debug the issue a bit. In the inspector turn on debugging mode. If you are unsure how to do this I can help when not on mobile. After turning it on select the EventSystem when in play. It should display the actively hovered object it is detecting. Try hovering over objects then clicking in various places as well as dragging. See if anything unexpected is listed there.

Comment: I would recommend though to extend the functionality of the EventSystem to cache the most recent event especially anything dragged. If the issue is whenever you drag an object the camera drags, by caching your most recent action and exposing it, you can easily detect when not to move the camera. The prior links I posted should point you in the right direction. If you need a more formal answer I can type one up.

Comment: Many thanks @TEEBQNE for your help, but I tried multiple approaches and they all failed. So I just ended up going with a paid asset LeanTouch+ to handle this for me.

Comment: Gotcha. Well at least you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path as

```
!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
```

is the right way forward, but make sure to use it like this:

```
// Check if the left mouse button was clicked
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Check if the mouse was clicked over a UI element
            if(!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            {
                Debug.Log("Did not Click on the UI");
            }
        }
```

Make sure that the RaycastTarget toggle on your UI component is not enabled.
Also, check the Event Mask in the Physics Raycaster on your camera. IsPointerOverGameObject() will return true if the mouse is over any objects on those layers. If you only want to check for the UI layer, make sure that only UI is checked.

Here are some references:

[EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject Docu.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseInputModule.html?q=IsPointerOver)

[EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html)

[Thread that might help you](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ispointerovergameobject-returns-always-true.520060/)

Comment: I fail to see how the above snippet is any different from OPs code in the question.

Comment: I was just reinforcing and reminding him to use it like this! The latins would say "repetita iuvant" :)